# JDO Class - convert to varchar or nvarchar based on MySQL or MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, jdo, datanucleus, persistence-manager

I have a JDO Class. Some of the attributes are as shown below:

```
@Column(jdbcType = "VARCHAR", length = 200)
String anotherSrcFieldValue;

@Column(jdbcType = "BIGINT")
long tgtFieldId;

@Column(jdbcType = "VARCHAR", length = 200)
String tgtFieldValue;
```

With MySQL and MSSQL it works fine.

My requirement is, if it is MySQL make it a column of type VARCHAR; and when it is MSSQL, create a column of type NVARCHAR. How can I achieve this?

A second requirement is one entity class to be run on both the databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All JDO docs I've seen explain clearly that putting schema specific info in annotations is a bad idea. Consequently you should have 2 files "*package-mysql.orm*" and "*package-mssql.orm*" to specify the schema-specific parts of the mapping, and set "`datanucleus.Mapping`" to be either "*mysql*" or "*mssql*" depending on your datastore. As per http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jdo/orm/metadata_orm.html

Comment: And dont forget to ACCEPT this answer when you see that it answers what you asked